# Replace all occurrences of double comma with a single comma

Tags: javascript, regex

I need `hello,,,,,,,,,,,world` to become `hello,world`

I have this but it only replaces 2 commas

```
s = s.replace(/\,\,/g,',');
```

How can I replace more than one comma after another with a single comma?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

```
s = s.replace(/,+/g,',');
```

A `+` in a regular expression means "one *or more* of the previous thing, in a row." So `,+` means "one *or more* commas in a row."

Answer (score 5):

Also can use `{2,}` to specify match more than 1

```
s = s.replace(/,{2,}/g, ',');
```

Comment: Good point, not reason to do the replacements where only one matches.